# VBA project explorershowing excel workbooks after closing them with macro

Tags: vba, excel

As the title suggests, after closing another workbook that runs a macro it keeps showing up in the VBA Explorer.

What the macro is doing:

1. Open a template workbook
2. Copies data to it from the current workbook
3. Saves it under a different name

All the above is enclosed in a loop, since I need to be able to do this for a few dozen entries.

I have tried clearing the objects from memory but apparently I'm still doing something wrong.

Macro code:

```
Sub Openworkbook_Click()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161008
    Dim sWb As Workbook
    Dim dWb As Workbook
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim newName As String
    Dim relPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Set sWb = ActiveWorkbook

    'While loop
    i = 3
    Do While sWb.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i) <> ""
    'Set destination workbook
        Set dWb = Workbooks.Open("D:\1. WORK\AUDA\in progress\Betonvæg_test.xlsm")

        'Geometry copy
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K13").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K14").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K15").PasteSpecial

        'Reinforcement copy
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("G" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("J19").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("H" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K19").PasteSpecial

        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("I" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("J20").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("J" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K20").PasteSpecial

        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("K" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("J21").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("L" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K21").PasteSpecial

        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("M" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("J22").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("N" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("K22").PasteSpecial

        'Material properties
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("E17").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("F" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("E18").PasteSpecial

        'Other
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("O" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("E12").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("P" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("E13").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("Q" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("E14").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("R" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("E15").PasteSpecial

        'Copy loads
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("S" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("F33").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("T" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("G33").PasteSpecial

        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("U" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("F34").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("V" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("G34").PasteSpecial

        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("W" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("G35").PasteSpecial
        sWb.Sheets(1).Range("X" & i).Copy
        dWb.Sheets(1).Range("F35").PasteSpecial

        'Save with different name & close
        newName = "Betonvæg_" & sWb.Sheets(1).Range("C" & i) & "x" & sWb.Sheets(1).Range("D" & i) & ".xlsm"
        relPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        dWb.SaveAs Filename:=relPath & newName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Workbooks(newName).Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Clear destination object
        Set dWb = Nothing

        'Increment i to read next line
        i = i + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Try commenting out the line `On Error Resume Next` and re-running the code. It's possible that errors are occurring but getting supressed.

Comment: Hi, commented out the line. The only error I was getting is that the template I was trying ot change was protected. Solved that.
What I noticed today was that if I run the macro from the sheet without having the VBA Explorer opened, no extra workbook shows up when I check afterwards. However if I run the macro with the VBA explorer opened the closed workbooks always remain there.

Answer (score 0):

Close workbook using `dWb.Close SaveChanges:=True` instead `Workbooks(newName).Close SaveChanges:=True`

Comment: Unfortunately tried that and it's still not working :(